# woocommerce attributes with shipping

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

The website i am working on sells plants.  Most products are variable products with different Height(Metres) and also Pot size (Litres).  How do i get these custom attributes to affect the shipping rate?  In native PHP this would be so easy but working within wordpress i don't know where to begin.  I want to do:

If `Pot Size > 25L` and `Height > 2m`, then add $4 to the shipping.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, i would be grateful.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your products then attributes. Add your attribute name which is height, colour etc... then add values 2m, >25l.
Go to your product, change "Product data" from "simple product" to "variable product".
Add attribute which is height (don't forget to add values), thick "used for variation" box and then go to "variations" and set up prices.